# Algorithm to get an approximate depth map from an embossed/relief image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am attempting to read information from pictures of hard plastic ID cards.  As a first step, I've been trying to process the pictures to make the text more computer-readable.  The pictures are fairly clear, but they are tricky because they are light on one side and dark on the other.  It seems like it should be possible to use this information to create a depth map, which could then be converted to a black and white image.  Mainly, I'd like to know if there is some known algorithm (the simpler the better) I could implement.  I'm currently doing the rest of the processing using Python and PIL, but any implementation I could adapt would be great.

A small example of the images I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: You can upload images to e.g. http://imgur.com and link them here. The "emboss" images you find on google are typically results of computer graphics, while your sample is (it's a camera-taken picture).

Comment: I've added a link to an example; thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The idea is to OCR them somehow? Is the light always coming from the same direction?

Comment: @jdv Not necessarily, but this will be an automated process that could try multiple angles to find the one that produces the best OCR data.  I couldn't find an algorithm to do it even knowing the angle.

Comment: The "multiple light angles" to get a depth map is called "photometric stereo", and for a single light source it's called "shape from shading", if you need keywords to find what you're looking for - it's not actually my field, so i can't tell you more than that, but if you're just looking to recognize the digits, going for the depth map is probably not neccessary - see @belisarius answer.

Comment: @etarion Thanks for the keywords.  Everytime I searched for relief I got disaster relief and emboss always yielded steps for making embossed pictures.

Comment: @101100 Please note that "shape from shading", as mentioned by @etarion is the right path to go _if_ you can't avoid it :). It is much more cumbersome than the approach below, and I think you are not after a 3D representation ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Example in Mathematica. If the result is satisfactory I could explain the procedure step by step.

```
Erosion[
 ColorNegate@
  Thinning@
   Dilation[
    DeleteSmallComponents[
     DeleteBorderComponents@
      ColorNegate@
       Binarize@Import["http://i.imgur.com/GLzvj.png"],
     150],
    8],
 8]
```

[image]

**Edit**

Step by step ...

Starting with

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is what I was aiming for!  I see the negate and assume that is inverting the picture, but could you explain the other steps?

Comment: @101100 The `ColorNegate[]` is just because the following functions (DeleteBorderComponents[], for example) identifies the "components" as being white. It's just a platform nuisance, nothing important there. I'll update the answer showing  step by step results.